# Metal in-place operation for `MTLComputeCommandEncoder ` on iOS

Tags: ios, metal

Is it possible to have a Metal compute function that processes a texture in-place on iOS? I have noticed that some `MPS` image filters support in-place processing, and was wondering if there is a way to accomplish this with custom kernels.

Specifically, I am looking to combine two textures into one using a blend function. I am easily able to do this by making the first texture a render target and using a shader to write the second one on top, but it feels like an overkill since both textures are the same size.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can take a texture parameter with the `access::read_write` attribute, and read and write it within the same kernel function invocation. You'll need to ensure that the texture is created with both the `.read` and `.write` usage flags. Additionally, note that writes are not guaranteed to be seen by any subsequent reads by the same thread unless you call the `flush()` function after the write.

By the way, MetalPerformanceShaders kernels that are able to operate "in-place" don't necessarily use `read_write` textures; it's often the case that they use auxiliary textures and buffers and do their work across multiple passes. Per [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalperformanceshaders/mpsunaryimagekernel/1618873-encode), any kernel can fail to operate in-place for any number of reasons, so you should always provide a fallback allocator to handle such cases.